# Why is image rotator jumpy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I've created a simple website with a moving image gallery and a round slider to control it. I've managed to get the slider to control the gallery in both directions but whenever the slider value goes back to zero (because the user has gone all the way round) the rotator jumps once the opposite way to the user's movement. The rotator also occasionally stops and on;y resumes when one whole rotation has been completed.

Here is a link to:

The round slider site: roundsliderui.com

The rotator site: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/infinite-photo-carousel/

The jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kku69m6/5/

I do appreciate any help with this so thanks in advance,

Mitra0000

```
/*Code is too large to display here*/
```